# How to get a generic method's value in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I have this generic method:

```
public Guid Save<T>(T obj)
    {
        Guid newId = Guid.NewGuid();
        try
        {
            foreach (MethodInfo method in (typeof(T)).GetMethods())
            {
                if (IsXmlElement(method))
                {
                    // A way to get this method's value
                    // e.g. if T has method GetName, and GetName was assigned 'John' 
                    //i.e. object.GetName = 'John'Is there a way to get 'John' from this GetName method?
                }
            }
```

Then, I have an object, `myObject.Name = 'John'`... and myObject was passed to save method thus: `Save(myObject);` Is there any way I can get the value 'John' inside the Save method?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is IsXmlElement? 
Why do you say that GetName is a method and use it like a property? `object.GetName = 'John'`
Also, value can be assigned to a filed or a property, in case of method it is likely a result of calculation, and it could also require parameters. Where will you take those parameters from?

Comment: That is just a method to check if that method has a particular attribute... - though that is not necessary for this question

Comment: Please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method

Comment: Are you interested in how to invoke any generic method, or how to restrict  your generic types to those that have a specific method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate through the properties (I assume you mean properties when you say "methods" from your example) based on the generic type, you can use the `TypeDescriptor` class:

```
public Guid Save<T>(T obj)
{
    Guid newId = Guid.NewGuid();
    try
    {
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)))
        {
            if (IsXmlElement(method))
            {
                object value = property.GetValue(obj);
                // ...
            }
        }
```

If you always infer the type (i.e. `T` is always the type of `obj` and not a base type or interface), you don't need generics at all:

```
public Guid Save(object obj)
{
    Guid newId = Guid.NewGuid();
    try
    {
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
        {
            if (IsXmlElement(method))
            {
                object value = property.GetValue(obj);
                // ...
            }
        }
```

You might want to also check out the `XmlSerializer` class. It seems that you are creating an XML from your source object manually. `XmlSerializer` probably has already everything you need with less work.

Comment: thanks a lot @Sefe. This solution works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would enforce an requirement that any type passed to your generic method is derived from a common interface.  Then you can reference any of the properties that are defined in that interface (in this case `name`).  Your method definition would look something like this:

```
 public Guid Save<T>(T obj) where T : iSaveable
 { 
    ...
```

where `iSaveable` would be the name of the interface you created.

Comment: enforcing requirement won't resolve my issue. This is because properties I would want to get values for a not specific/fixed. These are propeties of classes that has certain attribute. A new class could be added, with custom properties, but if any of those properties contain this attribute, it would qualify for value retrieval

Answer (score 1):

It really sounds like you are looking to work with properties rather than methods in this example.  In the case of properties you would write something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = new TestObject();
    foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = '{1}'", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj));
    }
}

class TestObject
{
    public TestObject()
    {
        FirstName = "John";
        LastName = "Hancock";
    }

    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
}
```

You could also use this to get the values of fields instead of properties by changing the `GetProperties` call to `GetFields`.  This will only work with public fields or properties though.  If you wanted to wanted to save non-public fields or properties you would need to add `BindingFlags` to the `GetProperties`/`GetFields` call:

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = new TestObject();
    foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = '{1}'", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj));
    }
}

class TestObject
{
    private readonly string _firstName;
    private readonly string _lastName;

    public TestObject()
    {
        _firstName = "John";
        _lastName = "Hancock";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you contribution @Trey Tomes. My mistake actually, I was actually looking to work with properties. I posted the question before realizing this

Comment: That's no problem @osagie.  I'm happy to have interpreted your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the object to the known type then access the `Name` property. Because you don't show us your classes, let's pretend your object is of type `Person`, then inside `Save`:

```
if (obj is Person)
{
    string name = ((Person)obj).Name;
} 
else
{ ... }
```

More info about `is` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can if you put a constraint on the type parameter like this:

```
public Guid Save<T>(T obj) where T : ISomeInterface
    {
        Guid newId = Guid.NewGuid();
        try
        {
            foreach (MethodInfo method in (typeof(T)).GetMethods())
            {
                if (IsXmlElement(method))
                {
                    // A way to get this method's value
                    // e.g. if T has method GetName, and GetName was assigned 'John' 
                    //i.e. object.GetName = 'John'Is there a way to get 'John' from this GetName method?
                }
            }
```

and where your myObject implements the ISomeInterface interface.

Hope that helps